# Why don't dicarboxylic acids show hydrogen bonding in spite of the fact that carboxylic acids exist usually as dimers in polar aprotic solvent?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, carbonyl-compounds, hydrogen-bond

I have seen several examples:

1. The fact that maleic acid is more soluble in water than fumaric acid in spite of the fact that it must be able to show intramolecular hydrogen bonding.
2. *trans*-Cyclopentane-1,2-dicarboxylic acid is more stable than the *cis* form (*cis* form should be able to show hydrogen bonding).
3. *o*-Nitrobenzoic acid is more acidic than the *para* isomer.

I tried linking point 1 to acidic strength (maleic acid > fumaric acid because of hydrogen bonding in conjugate base) and point 3 to acidic strength (*o*-nitrophenol < *p*-nitrophenol)

What am I missing? Something related to the size of the ring?

Comment: Refer to these papers: [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00983a024), [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15962275/) and [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ol005776j)

Comment: This is a prime example of question that's both badly worded and too broad.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to object the statement dicarboxylic acids would not engage hydrogen bonding.  Terephthalic acids ($\ce{HO2C-C6H4-CO2H}$) are a prominent example since early attempts to formalize the description of intra- and intermolecular hydrogen bonding in the solid state. Consider the pairing of benzoïc acid and $p$-terephthalic acid, sharing the same motif of hydrogen donors and acceptors, described as $R_2^2(8)$ in Etter's notation:

[image]

(Etter, *Acc. Chem. Res.* 1990, **23**, 120-126,  [doi 10.1021/ar00172a005](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ar00172a005))

But there is no limit to $p$-substitution to find this motif again, e.g.:

[image]

(Holy *et al.*, *Collect. Czech. Chem. Commun.* 2006, **71**, 139-154, [doi 10.1135/cccc20060139](http://cccc.uochb.cas.cz/71/2/0139/), [researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/31912822_Synthesis_and_Self-Assembly_of_99%27-Spirobifluorene-22%2777%27-tetracarboxylic_Acid_and_Its_Tetraamide_Non-Catenated_Formation_of_Achiral_Grid_Layers_with_Large_Chiral_Pores))

Comment: But why exactly isn't hydrogen bonding predominant in explaining the 3 specific cases I mentioned in my question.  Would really appreciate your help and support.